# Best way to sanitize / validate PDF document in ColdFusion

Tags: validation, pdf, coldfusion

I'm using ColdFusion 10 and accepting an uploaded PDF file from the user.  I want to sanitize/validate the PDF file to ensure it is actually a PDF file, and not some other type of file renamed as *.pdf.

Currently my strategy is to run `<cfpdf action="merge" name="pdfdata">` on the file, and then call `toBinary(pdfdata)` when saving the result, but I'm getting a strange problem with a PDF that's valid afaict but raises a PDFDocException error when `toBinary(pdfdata)` is called.

Is there a "right way" to sanitize/validate the PDF document upon upload?

Comment: try/catch on reading the uploaded file?

Comment: <cfif not ListFindnoCase("pdf",fileUpload.ServerFileExt) or not IsPDFFile("path")> <cfset errorMSG="some error">...you could try something like this

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion has a built-in function to verify whether a PDF file is valid or not; `IsPDFFile()`. I have no idea how it works or what it checks though.

[Here is the ColdFusion documentation for the IsPDFFile function](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/IsPDFFile)

> **Description**
>
> Verifies whether a PDF file is valid.
>
> **Returns**
>
> True, if the value returns a valid PDF file. False, otherwise.
>
> **Function syntax**
>
> `IsPDFFile("path")`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *path* - Pathname to an on-disk or in-memory PDF file. The pathname can be absolute or relative to the CFM page and must be enclosed in quotation marks.
>
> **Usage**
>
> This function returns False if the value is not a valid pathname to a PDF file, the pathname is null, the PDF file is not valid, or the PDF file is corrupted.

And I would also suggest that you read over this reference from Pete Freitag: [Tips for Secure File Uploads with ColdFusion](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm)